# FitNesse Error while executing Sikuli code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, fitnesse, sikuli

I am trying to execute sikuli code through FitNesse.

the following error is displayed.

```
Could not detect death of command line test runner.
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Native Method)
        at fitnesse.testsystems.CommandRunner.join(CommandRunner.java:86)
        at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimTestSystem.bye(SlimTestSystem.java:117)
```

Same code is working through eclipseIde but while running Test from FitNesse

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for someone to figure this out, and I doubt that anyone else has seen your exact problem.  Also, please talk about things you've tried to do to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information on the observed issue:
I have integrated Sikuli code for upload a file  and following is the Sikuli code for upload:

```
public void uploadSikiuliCode(String image){

                       String target ="C:/Users/TestQA/Desktop/TextBox.png";
                            Screen s = new Screen();
                            try{
                                            s.click(target,0);
                                            s.type(image, 0);
                                            waitForPageLoad(3);
                                            s.click("C:/Users/TestQA/Desktop/Open.png",0);                                                         
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
```

}

I have executed and able to upload file using Eclipse IDE
I have integrated the same to FitNesse and executed it was working fine till it enters into the Sikuli (upload) method 
After entering into the method while executing the 
Screen s = New Screen ()

The following error is displayed

```
Could not detect death of command line test runner.java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Native Method)
    at fitnesse.testsystems.CommandRunner.join(CommandRunner.java:86)
    at fitnesse.testsystems.slim.SlimTestSystem.bye(SlimTestSystem.java:117)
```